# Page renders before UseEffect updates state

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jsx

i want to prepend a textbox thats makes a API call when the page is initially loaded.

Both console logs are able to print out the result , but in the render it comes to NULL, my guess is it renders before the API call , how should i do to make wait the axios call before it renders first?

```
const [myAddr, getAddr] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const grabAddress = async () => {
      const url = "http://localhost:5001/getAddress";
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const data = response.data;
        console.log("the addr is ", data["result"]);
        getAddr(data.result);
        return data;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error:" + e);
      }
    };
    grabAddress();
  }, []);
  console.log("useEffect:", myAddr);
```

render =>

```
 <TextField
            defaultValue={myAddr}
             ..reset of code
            }}
          ></TextField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first render myAddr will be null for sure, and then API call will be sent by React to fill data in myAddr. You need to conditionally render it making sure myAddr exists like this:

```
{myAddr && <TextField
            defaultValue={myAddr}
             ..reset of code
            }}
          ></TextField>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple if condition to check if data(myAddr) is loaded.

```
render() {
 if(myAddr) {
    return (
       <TextField
            defaultValue={myAddr}
             ..reset of code
            }}>
       </TextField>
    )
 }
}
```